# Llama-cpp-python on AWS Sagemaker - Failed building wheel for llama-cpp-python

Tags: python, c++, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface, langchain

I am using AWS Sagemaker Notebook Instances to interact with LLaMA models because Colab Pro only offers 15GB GPU RAM and always runs out of memory (CUDA Out of Memory), whereas my sagemaker notebook is a ml.g5.2xlarge instance or a ml.g4dn.2xlarge instance and should not have any problem with that. However, when I run this command:

```
!pip install llama-cpp-python==0.1.48
```

I get the following error message (output is 130 lines, so I condensed it to most relevant parts)

```
Building wheel for llama-cpp-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
exit code: 1 [130 lines of output  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and 
is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for llama-cpp-python
Failed to build llama-cpp-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for llama-cpp-python, which is required to install 
pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: for LLaMA-7B model in full precision, you need 7 * 4 = 28GB of GPU RAM… g5.2xlarge has only 24. regardless, the error message included is not related to this. please post the whole error, and let us know what pre-requisites you have installed

Answer (score 0):

You need Visual C++ on your machine. Download and install, place in the PATH and your error should resolve. If you are on cloud, you need VC++ in the environment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).